# Neo4jError: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS

Tags: node.js, neo4j

i want to acces to the database but i got this error. Here is the code:

```
const neo4j = require("neo4j-driver").v1;
const driver = neo4j.driver(
  "bolt://localhost:7687",
  neo4j.auth.basic("neo4j", "1234")    
);
      const session = driver.session();    
app.post("/registro", function(req, res) {  
        var nombre = req.body.nombre;
        var apellidos= req.body.apellidos;
        var email= req.body.email;
        var pass= req.body.pass;
        session.run("MATCH (user:Usuario {email:"+email+"}) RETURN user")
        .then(results => {    
      if (!_.isEmpty(results.records)) {
              console.log("error")
          }
          else {
        console.log("bien")
      }
    })    
    .catch(error => {    
      session.close();
      console.log(error);
      driver.close()    
    })    
});
```

and I got this error:

```
*Neo4jError: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
at captureStacktrace (S:\sergi\Documents\INFORMATICA\4º Curso Informatica\1º Cuatrimestre\SIGBI\Practica\SIGBI\Backend\node_modules\neo4j-driver\lib\v1\result.js:199:15)
at new Result (S:\sergi\Documents\INFORMATICA\4º Curso Informatica\1º Cuatrimestre\SIGBI\Practica\SIGBI\Backend\node_modules\neo4j-driver\lib\v1\result.js:65:19)
at Session._run (S:\sergi\Documents\INFORMATICA\4º Curso Informatica\1º Cuatrimestre\SIGBI\Practica\SIGBI\Backend\node_modules\neo4j-driver\lib\v1\session.js:154:14)
at Session.run (S:\sergi\Documents\INFORMATICA\4º Curso Informatica\1º Cuatrimestre\SIGBI\Practica\SIGBI\Backend\node_modules\neo4j-driver\lib\v1\session.js:130:19)
at S:\sergi\Documents\INFORMATICA\4º Curso Informatica\1º Cuatrimestre\SIGBI\Practica\SIGBI\Backend\app.js:28:13
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (S:\sergi\Documents\INFORMATICA\4º Curso Informatica\1º Cuatrimestre\SIGBI\Practica\SIGBI\Backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (S:\sergi\Documents\INFORMATICA\4º Curso Informatica\1º Cuatrimestre\SIGBI\Practica\SIGBI\Backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (S:\sergi\Documents\INFORMATICA\4º Curso Informatica\1º Cuatrimestre\SIGBI\Practica\SIGBI\Backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (S:\sergi\Documents\INFORMATICA\4º Curso Informatica\1º Cuatrimestre\SIGBI\Practica\SIGBI\Backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at S:\sergi\Documents\INFORMATICA\4º Curso Informatica\1º Cuatrimestre\SIGBI\Practica\SIGBI\Backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22 {
code: 'ServiceUnavailable',
name: 'Neo4jError'
}*
```

how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the neo4j with encryption?
I think you should send the basic config on driver creation

```
const driver = neo4j.driver(
  "bolt://localhost:7687",
  neo4j.auth.basic("neo4j", "1234"),
  { encrypted: true }   
);
```